# How to generate GUI with multiple buttons and incrementing labels on them?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, tostring

I am trying to generate a GUI using swing that creates a frame with 100 buttons and every button has a "label" on it from on 1 to a 100.

What I have tried:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonScreen extends JFrame{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int rows=10;
    int cols=10;
    JButton[][] button = new JButton[rows][cols];
    JTextArea screen = new JTextArea();
    JPanel bpanel = new JPanel();
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        ButtonScreen bs = new ButtonScreen();
        bs.setVisible(true);
    }// end of main

   public ButtonScreen(){
    super("Welcome to the ButtonScreen Program!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    bpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols));


    for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<button.length;j++){
            
                button[i][j]=new JButton(""+i+j);
                bpanel.add(button[i][j]);
         }
    }
    add(bpanel);
   }//end of constructor
}//end of class
```

This works just fine, but it creates buttons with "labels" (meaning string parameters at line 26) and also these labels, are not one string or one integer but it is a dillusion of the of i right next to j counter. So my second attempt, after some corrections, was:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class LabArr extends JFrame{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int rows=10;
    int cols= 10;
    int i=0;
    JButton[][] button = new JButton[rows][cols];
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[100];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabArr la = new LabArr();
        la.setVisible(true);
    }//end of main 

    public LabArr(){
        super("title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols));

        for(i=0;i<label.length;i++){
            label[i]= new JLabel(toString(i));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<button.length;j++){
                button[i][j]= new JButton(""+label[j]);
              
               add(button[i][j]);
            }
        }


    }//end of constructor

    public String toString(int k){
        k=i;
        String s;
        s=""+k;
        return s;
    }
    
}//end of class
```

My goal using that was to create an array of JLabel objects and then match every JLabel element to one from the JButton array.

So, first of all I would like to know to which object the methods setLayout and setDefaultCloseOperation refer to.

Second, "Does the toString method need to refer to an object at the line I am using it?". And finally, what am I missing?

Comment: Try generating your labels like this: `button[i][j]=new JButton(""+(i * cols + j + 1));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a single frame with buttons from 1 to 100.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class HundredButtonGrid{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("100 buttons");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
            frame.add( new JButton( "" + (i + 1) ) );
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I've addressed a few things.

- I just use 1 index because the GridLayout takes care of the x/y values.
- I used parenthesis to add the index to 1 so that it doesn't end up concatenating them by string.
- I've set the default close operation to exit, you can have it do other things too. Like `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` so the window will go away, but not terminate the application.
- I didn't extend JFrame, I created a separate instance. In your case you have extended JFrame, so when you call `setLayout` it is being called on the instance you're creating. An alternative way to say it is `this.setLayout` same with `setDefaultCloseOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you with your problem, kindly see the code below:

```
public class LabArr extends JFrame{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int rows=10;
    int cols= 10;
    int counter = 0;

    JButton[][] button = new JButton[rows][cols];
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[rows*cols];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoApplication la = new DemoApplication();
        la.setVisible(true);
    }//end of main

    public LabArr(){
        super("title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols));

        for(int i=0;i<label.length;i++){
            label[i]= new JLabel(toString(i));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<button.length;j++){
                button[i][j]= new JButton(counter + "");

                add(button[i][j]);
                counter++;
            }
        }


    }//end of constructor

    public String toString(int k){

        String s;
        s=""+k;
        return s;
    }

}
```

You've been creating the buttons with the label `toString()` method name.